# Why check if file is exists in shell always false?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I created a cron using bash to delete files older than 3 days, but when checking the age of the files with mtime +3 &> /dev/null it is always false. here's the script:

```
now=$(date)

create log file

file_names=('*_takrib_golive.gz' '*_takrib_golive_filestore.tar.gz')
touch /media/nfs/backup/backup_delete.log
echo "Date: $now" >> /media/nfs/backup/backup_delete.log
for filename in "${file_names[@]}";
do
 echo $filename

        if ls /media/nfs/backup/${filename} &> /dev/null
        then
                echo "backup files exist"
                if find /media/nfs/backup -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -name ${filename} -ls &> /dev/null
                then
                        echo "The following backup file was deleted" >> /media/nfs/backup/backup_delete.log 
                        find /media/nfs/backup -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -name ${filename} -delete
                else
                        echo "There are no ${filename} files older than 3 days in /media/nfs/backup" &>> /media/nfs/backup/backup_delete.log
                fi
        else
                echo "No ${filename} files found in /media/nfs/backup" >> /media/backup/backup_delete.log
        fi
done
exit 0
```

in `if find /media/nfs/backup -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -name ${filename} -ls &> /dev/null` always goes to else, even though files older than 3 days are in the directory

Comment: Not your question, but `if ls /media/nfs/backup/${filename} &> /dev/null` should be `if test -e "/media/nfs/backup/${filename}"` and you should always quote your variables.

Comment: Do you get any errors from `find`? Get rid of the output redirection and see if you have errors (if it always goes to false, it hints at having a non-1 exit code)

Comment: `&>` is a syntax error in `sh`. See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). How exactly are you running this script?

Comment: no error occurs when I run find outside the shell script that I created, when I run it like this `find /media/nfs/backup -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -name ${filename} -ls` can output results but when I run this script `find /media/nfs/backup -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -name ${filename} -ls &> /dev/null` nothing appears

Comment: @Admaja please remove the error redirection in your script and see if you get any errors in the script. You can also try running it with `-x` enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not quoting the `-name` attribute so it expands to the name of the file which already exists.

I would refactor this rather extensively anyway. [Don't parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and perhaps simplify this by making it more obvious when to quote and when not to.

Untested, but hopefully vaguely useful still:

```
#!/bin/bash

backup=/media/nfs/backup
backuplog=$backup/backup_delete.log
# no need to touch if you write to the file anyway
date +"Date: %C" >> "$backuplog"

# Avoid using a variable, just loop over the stems
for stem in takrib_golive takrib_golive_filestore.tar
do
    # echo $filename
    # Avoid parsing ls; instead, loop over matches
    for filename in "$backup"/*_"$stem".gz; do
        pattern="*_$stem.gz"
        if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
            echo "backup files exist"
            if files=$(find "$backup" -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -false -o -name "$pattern" -print -delete)
            then
                echo "The following backup file was deleted" >> "$backuplog"
                echo "$files" >> "$backuplog"
            else
                echo "There are no $pattern files older than 3 days in $backup" >> "$backuplog"
            fi
        else
            echo "No $pattern files found in $backup" >> "$backuplog"
        fi
        # Either way, we can break the loop after one iteration
        break
    done
done
# no need to explicitly exit 0
```

The `for` + `if [ -e ... ]` arrangement is slightly clumsy, but that's how you check if a wildcard matched any files.  If the wildcard did not match, `if [ -e`   will check for a file whose name is literally the wildcard expression itself, and fail.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be cleaner to turn on _nullglob_? If nothing matches the pattern, the loop is simply not executed. The message for no files being found can be generated by a flag, which is turned on once the first file has been found.

Comment: thanks, but there is still an error at the end of the line, it says `line 25: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Sorry, added the missing `done`. Thanks for the pings.

Comment: @user1934428 `setopt -s nullglob` would work instead, absolutely. I tried to stick to reasonably POSIX syntax in case that would simplify things for the OP.

Comment: almost, but there is still an error, namely the `name` error message appears `find: paths must precede expression: `name'` , then I tried to change it to `-name` it worked. but all files were deleted, so I removed `-false` and `-o`. and it works as i want. thanks again you saved my day.

Comment: The point of `-false -o` is to produce an error if no files are found, but I guess I will have to refactor it to work correctly. Sorry again for the typos; I added the missing dash in `-name` now.